# Mass-replace in a bunch of Word files?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, automation, openoffice

Is there a way to do string replacement automatically in a large number of Word files?

Bonus points if your answer includes a way to do it for OpenDocument files as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) does the job just fine. Will work for all of those types of files.

Comment: Is it smart enough to work on compressed file such as .docx files?

Comment: I would assume not. Look for a mass converter type thing, but I am not sure.

Comment: Edited answer, they have a plugin for docx files.